# Dynamically display labels in column chart

Tags: anychart

Is there any possibility to dynamically display labels in colums charts ?
In this example (https://playground.anychart.com/DUMbYxdg/5) labels overlap and i would like to choose whether or not to display each label.

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can don't show labels for points with small value to avoid overlapping. For this purpose, you can use formatting function instead of a string token. We have modified your sample to show how it works. You can find the sample in the comment below.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer !

Answer (score 0):

Could not find-out solution from this link https://playground.anychart.com/DUMbYxdg/5 to fix the overlapping issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).