# AnyChart: Dynamically display labels in column chart

Tags: anychart

Is there any possibility to dynamically display labels in colums charts ? In this example (https://playground.anychart.com/DUMbYxdg/5) labels overlap and i only want to display only labels that fit in the column.

In another post ([Dynamically display labels in column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391178/dynamically-display-labels-in-column-chart)) an answer refers to a comment with a solution but this comment is not there.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust labels dynamically, based on thief value, you must utilize the [getStat method](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.cartesian.series.Column#getStat) and [custom formatting functions](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Text_Formatters#formatting_functions), instead of tokens.

```
  // dynamically apply labels formatting
  labels.format(function(){
  if(this.getStat("yPercentOfCategory") > 3){
    return this.getStat("yPercentOfCategory") + "%"
   }
  });
```

This solution applies the formatting function only for elements, greater than 3% of the total series value. We have prepared a [playground demo of using setStat and a custom formatting function](https://playground.anychart.com/DfanlWGd/2) for you with this solution. Please feel free to explore it.